# Basic ToDo List storing the data

Tags: jquery

I have been working to put together a to do list application from scratch. So far I have used HTML, CSS, Javascript and JQuery to do this. I have now got all the base functionality working for the most part. Now comes the hard part which is actually storing and retrieving real data to display.

I know php/mysql would work for this, but I am trying to keep this basic for my first big project and not overwhelm myself. So I though AJAX would work, but it seems that AJAX can only read filed and not right them. So now I am wondering what a good basic language or technology would be to use to get and store the data. Maybe AJAX and XML file? But do I still need another language? Or can it all by client side?

https://jsfiddle.net/pnewelljr/jqdkfLdx/38/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(document).on("click",".items",function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    
    $(document).on("click","li", function () {
        $("li").removeAttr("class");
        $(this).attr("class","selectedlist");
        $(".items, #itemsbar > p").remove();
        $("#itemsbar").append('<div class=\"items\" id=\"c1div\"><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"c1\" name=\"c1\" /> \
        <label for=\"c1\"><span></span>New Box~</label></div><p>Click to Add</p>');
    });
    
    $(document).on("click","#itemsbar > p",function () {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#itemsbar").append('<input class="addnew" type=\"text\"></input>');
    });
    
    $(document).on("keyup",'.addnew', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var value = $(".addnew").val();
            $("#itemsbar").append('<div class=\"items\" id=\"c1div\"><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"c1\" name=\"c1\" /> \
            <label for=\"c1\"><span></span>' + value + '</label></div>');
            $(this).remove();
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#itemsbar").append('<p>Click to Add</p>');
        }
    });
    
    $(document).on("click","#addlist",function() {
        $("#listsbar").append('<input class="addnewlist" type=\"text\"></input>');
    });

    $(document).on("keyup",'.addnewlist', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var value = $(".addnewlist").val();
            $("#lists").append('<li id="l3">' + value + '</li>');
            $(this).remove();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    
});
```

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 150%;
    color: white;
}

#title {
    float: left;
}

#main {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

/* Lists Bar */

#listsbar {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #6678AC;
}

#listsbar h1, li {
    padding: 10px;
}

#listsbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

#lists li {
    color: white;
}

.selectedlist {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0D1839;
    display: block;
}

/* Items Bar */

#itemsbar {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #C7D5FF;
}

#itemsbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="listsbar">
        <h1 id="title">To Do List</h1>
        <h1 id="addlist">+</h1>
        <ul id="lists">
            <li id="l1" class="selectedlist">Test List</li>
            <li id="l2">Test List 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="itemsbar">
        <div class="items" id="c1div"><input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="c1" />
        <label for="c1"><span></span>Check Box 1</label></div>
        <div class="items" id="c2div"><input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="c2" />
        <label for="c2"><span></span>Check Box 2</label></div>
        <p>Click to Add</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're likely going to want a server-side language and database to store the information. You could use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), or [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) to store the information on the user's computer, but all of those are temporary stores that risk being deleted.

Comment: For a real robust solution I definitely need one. I am mostly trying to make something that can show off my coding skills to a potential employer, so it is easier to send it to them if server side stuff isn't involved. Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to show off for a potential employer, then you should use a server-side solution. No client-side storage is going to be sufficient for professional situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For storing data you need a database or another place that can store data. You can't achive this by doing `client-side` work only. There are a lot of things  you can use: `php + mysql`, `.net +sql server`and so on.

Ajax is not a tool for storing data, it's just an 'option' to call an API( or a server side method ).

> Ajax is not a programming language or a tool, but a concept. Ajax is a
>   client-side script that communicates to and from a server/database
>   without the need for a postback or a complete page refresh. The best
>   definition I’ve read for Ajax is “the method of exchanging data with a
>   server, and updating parts of a web page - without reloading the
>   entire page.”

You said you are at the beginning, so I recommend you start learning a technology because you'll need it in the future. You can start with PHP ( from what I've heard it's easier than .NET )

Another tool you can use ( if you want to write javascript ) is `nodejs` which can play the server's role and it's written in `javascript`

Of course, there is a possibility to store data on client side, but I don't recommend it to you, mainly because you're at the beginning and you should learn some server side technology as well. I'm talking about storing data into `localStorage`

> localStorage is a way to store data on the client's computer.

Example :

```
localStorage.token= "12345";
// or
localStorage.setItem('token','12345');
```

Comment: For a real robust solution I definitely need one. I am mostly trying to make something that can show off my coding skills to a potential employer, so it is easier to send it to them if server side stuff isn't involved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Local Storage.

```
var data = document.getElementById('listsbar').innerHTML;
localStorage.setItem('ToDos',data);
```

And to retrieve it:

```
document.getElementById('listsbar').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('ToDos');
```

Here's an example of using localstorage on jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tobsta/xodfj5y5/

It works if you save it as an html file, but jsfiddle won't run it due to security issues. Here's a tutorial:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Because this is a to do list app, you'll want it to only save to the user's computer, not a server.

Comment: Can this store arrays? Like if I wanted to have an array for each list?

Comment: @Paul yes, it can store any data as long as you don't go over the 5megabyte limit. Hope you get the job :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save your data on the server, you must use a database (like mysql). If you can store data only on the client side, you can use localstorage to do that. Php can be your server-side language to get the datas from the database. Ajax will help you to get content without reloading the whole page. I recommend you to follow a simple tutorial. [This tutorial](http://mlitzinger.com/articles/simple-to-do-list/) can help you to do your to-do list. It use html, javascript, css, php, ajax, mysql.